# Problem with Python module "Schedule" for timed fan control

Tags: python, module, schedule

I wrote the code below to control a fan.

```
import schedule
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)              
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT) #set pin 14 as output

def aan(): 
    GPIO.output(14,0)    #set pin 14 to "low", fan comes on
    print(time.strftime("%H:%M")+" aan") #print time in hours and minutes, aan=on in Dutch

def uit():
    GPIO.output(14,1)    #set pin 14 to "high", fan goes off
    print(time.strftime("%H:%M")+" uit") #print time in hours and minutes, uit=off in Dutch
    
schedule.every().hour.at(":00").do(aan)
schedule.every().hour.at(":01").do(uit)
schedule.every().hour.at(":15").do(aan)
schedule.every().hour.at(":16").do(uit)
schedule.every().hour.at(":30").do(aan)
schedule.every().hour.at(":31").do(uit)
schedule.every().hour.at(":45").do(aan)
schedule.every().hour.at(":46").do(uit)

try:
    while True:
        if int(time.strftime("%H")) in range(9,21): #only preform the schedule between 9 and 21 hours
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

finally:
   print("clean up") 
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO pins
```

It is supposed to run for 1 minute at the 4 specified times in the schedule. The code works, but I've noticed from the print in the terminal that it also comes on 4 times on 09:00 (see below).

```
09:00 aan
09:00 uit
09:00 aan
09:00 uit
09:00 aan
09:00 uit
09:00 aan
09:00 uit
```

I've tried changing the :00 "on" and :01 "off" schedules, but this doesn't seem to make a difference. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would address the problem a little differently as illustrated below:

```
def fan():
    # Operate the fan 
    on_time = 60  # Runtime in seconds
    if int(time.strftime("%H")) in range(9,21): #only preform the schedule between 9 and 21 hours
        GPIO.output(14,0)    #set pin 14 to "low", fan comes on
        print(f'Turn on Fan at {time.strftime("%H:%M")}') 
        time.sleep(on_time)
        GPIO.output(14,1)    #set pin 14 to "high", fan goes off
        print(f'Turn Off Fan at {time.strftime("%H:%M")}')
```

Then:

```
schedule.every().hour.at(":00").do(fan)
while True:
        run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

else:
   print("clean up") 
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO pins
```

I can't fully test this code because I don't have your fan device, but this seems to work with just print statements.

Comment: The code works with my fan and the problem is gone. Thanks for the help!